# Script to copy a form field value of the same name from one PDF form to another in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, copy, field, acrobat

I have created a script (below) in Acrobat to copy a form field value from one PDF form to another but for whatever reason the script fails to perform as intended, i.e., copy the value to the other PDF form field. I should also add that I have tried running the script using a button with a mouse-up event and a menu item I have added to the PDF form as well. However, to my dismay, the script ends up copying the value to the JS console while the target PDF form field value remains empty. Any help regarding this subject matter is much appreciated.

```
// sample script to copy form field data from one PDF to another with the same form field name
var sourceFld = getField("dataSrc");
sourceFld.value = getField("dataSrc").value;// assign data/value to a var
var oTargetDoc = null;// script to access target doc
for(var i=0;i<app.activeDocs.length;i++){
  if(app.activeDocs[i] != this){
    oTargetDoc = app.activeDocs[i];
    break;
  }
}
if(oTargetDoc){
//get form field from target doc
  var targetFld = this.getField("dataSrc");
  targetFld.value = sourceFld.value;//copy data from source PDF field to target PDF data field
  
}
if(targetFld.value != ""){
  app.alert({
    cMsg: "Data Transfer Success!",
    Title: "EasyPDF™ Password Manager Copy Data",
    nIcon: 3
  });
  console.println(targetFld.value);//print the data copied to the target PDF form field to the JS console
}
else
  app.alert({
    cMsg: "Data Transfer Failed!",
    Title: "EasyPDF™ Password Manager Copy Data",
    nIcon: 3
  });
```

Ran script using a button as well as a menu item added to the form and script failed to perform as intended, i.e., copy a form field value from one PDF form to another.

Comment: What are you talking about, K J?? Interdocument communication has been in existence with Acrobat for way more than a decade, and it is easy to do. No need to fuzz around with other "utilities"!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the line

```
var targetFld = this.getField("dataSrc");
```

This refers to the currently active doc, which is not the target doc.

Correct would be

```
var targetFld = oTargetDoc.getField("dataSrc");
```

Another approach would be pulling from the target document; the concept is similar to pushing.

Also important: The document you want to access must have this

```
this.disclosed = true ;
```

on document level.

and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. Here's the script I ended up providing in the target doc using a popup menu item on the PDF form and it works like a charm:

```
var Ans = app.alert({
  cMsg: "Perform onetime copy/transfer data to update version of EasyPDF™ Password Manager?",
  Title: "Onetime EasyPDF™ Password Manager Copy/Transfer Data",
  nIcon: 2,
  nType: 2
})
if(Ans==4){
  var oSourceDoc = null;
  for(var i=0;i<app.activeDocs.length;i++){
    if(app.activeDocs[i] != this){
      oSourceDoc = app.activeDocs[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if(oSourceDoc){
  // copy data
    this.getField("dataSrc").value = oSourceDoc.getField("dataSrc").value// copy source PDF data/value to destination PDF data/value
    if(this.getField("dataSrc").value != ""){
      app.alert({
        cMsg: "Data Transfer Success!",
        Title: "EasyPDF™ Password Manager Copy Data",
        nIcon: 3
      });
    }
    else
      app.alert({
        cMsg: "Data Transfer Failed!",
        Title: "EasyPDF™ Password Manager Copy Data",
        nIcon: 3
      });
  }
}
```